# Loop through ajax response in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, loops

I got the following ajax response.

```
{"ord_item_Json_string":"[{\"code\":\"1002\",\"item\":\"Diamond Softy\",\"size\":\"15 inch\",\"color\":\"Light Blue\",\"qty\":\"2\",\"price\":\"849.45\",\"amount\":\"1698.90\"},{\"code\":\"1001\",\"item\":\"sAMPLE\",\"size\":\"Cob\",\"color\":\"Naturtal\",\"qty\":\"5\",\"price\":\"434.05\",\"amount\":\"2170.25\"}]"}
```

now the problem is that i want to display only code and item fields & value but i am unable. please help me how to access that fields.
my code is following.

```
$.ajax({
            url: base_url + 'order_jobcard/getOrderDetails/' + ord_id,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify($('ord_id').serializeArray()),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#OrdItem").html(data);
                console.log(data);
                return true;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Not Working');
                $('#ord_buyer_pack_inst').empty();
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
   
        var abc = {"ord_item_Json_string":"[{\"code\":\"1002\",\"item\":\"Diamond Softy\",\"size\":\"15 inch\",\"color\":\"Light Blue\",\"qty\":\"2\",\"price\":\"849.45\",\"amount\":\"1698.90\"},{\"code\":\"1001\",\"item\":\"sAMPLE\",\"size\":\"Cob\",\"color\":\"Naturtal\",\"qty\":\"5\",\"price\":\"434.05\",\"amount\":\"2170.25\"}]"}
        var a = JSON.parse(abc.ord_item_Json_string)
        $.each(a, function(index,value){
            console.log(value.code+'--'+value.item)
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried above but it shows 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Actually i got the error following line. like some error in parsing.
var a = JSON.parse(data.ord_item_Json_string);

Comment: Its working fine in **jsfiddle** too.
-- Please remove the included script from script part.
-- Copy link and **Resources URL** and add there.
-- Then run. if you do not get the result then use alert instead of console.log()

Comment: Console.log() result you should be check in inspect element in console tab. you got the result there.

Comment: I got the error in console
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at window.onload

Comment: in console 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: don't know why in my implementation it shows following error in console.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Answer (score 0):

try this: you can try below code where you can iterate over json array and read each attribute

```
$.ajax({
            url: base_url + 'order_jobcard/getOrderDetails/' + ord_id,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify($('ord_id').serializeArray()),
            success: function (data) {
                var dataStr = "";
                var jsonData = data.ord_item_Json_string; // this is already json
                jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);//value need to parse
             for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
               var ord= jsonData[i];
                console.log(ord.code);
                dataStr += ord.code;
              }
                $("#OrdItem").html(dataStr);
                console.log(data);
                return true;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Not Working');
                $('#ord_buyer_pack_inst').empty();
            }

        });
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3bLdnvr/16/)**

Comment: have you checked if you are getting `data` as JSON string or JSON? can you recreate it on code editor?

Comment: @HarunAnwar, i got the issue now. so data is json itself and no need to parse but the ord_item_Json_string value is string and need to parese. Please check my updated answer as well as https://jsfiddle.net/k3bLdnvr/16/

Answer (score 0):

try the code below...in success callback you will be getting data in json object format. so just get value using its key.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'order_jobcard/getOrderDetails/' + ord_id,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify($('ord_id').serializeArray()),
    success: function (jsonResponse) {


       var itemsList = jsonResponse.ord_item_Json_string;
       $.each(itemsList, function (index, value) {

           console.log(value.code + '--' + value.item);
        });
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: no luck... while troubleshoot when i alert itemsList the it shows undefined